# DNS MX record and SMTP server

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, spf

I have a SMTP server. DKIM is setup and working and have also setup SPF.

The SMTP host is `smtp.domain.com`

On the DNS I have a A record with `smtp` pointing to the IPv4 and a AAAA record with `smtp` pointing to the IPv6.

Regarding MX records I have one MX record for the IMAP server with target `mail`. I also had a MX record with target `smtp`

Everything was working perfect with both SPF and DKIM

Then one day I thought that the MX record with target `smtp` wasn't necessary - so I deleted it. But then my SPF auth stopped working

Is MX really necessary for SMTP or am I doing something wrong?

```
smtp             IN A 192.0.2.2
smtp             IN AAAA 2001:DB8::2
@                IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx -all"
@                IN MX 10 mail
@                IN MX 11 smtp <--- If this record is deleted SPF auth fails
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SPF record specifies two mechanisms, and the source IP for mail must match at least one of them:

- Either the `A` record for the domain (in this case the apex, since
  you don't specify anything after `a`), and/or
- One of the `MX` records must resolve to the source IP.

Assuming `mail` and `smtp` resolve to different IP addresses, removing the `MX` record for `smtp` means that it is no longer satisfies the `mx` mechanism.

Comment: But why does SPF not work after I delete MX smtp? There is still a A record with smtp..

Comment: The `a` expands to the current domain (by default the root domain), unless you write `a:smtp.yourdomain.com`.

Comment: Ok, so if I add `a:smtp.domain.com` in SPF I can delete the MX record for `smtp` ?

Comment: Yep, should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inheritance with SPF, which means two different things for your setup.

---

First, the SPF record allows or denies IP addresses and CIDR subnets, so everything other than `ip4` and `ip6` mechanisms (and `all`) are actually references to other DNS records.

- The `a` mechanism ([RFC 7208, 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.3)) without the `:<domain>` and/or `/<prefix-length>` refers to the 's IP addresses (both `A` and `AAAA` records) of the target.
- The `mx` mechanism ([RFC 7208, 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.4)) without the `:<domain>` and/or `/<prefix-length>` refers to the IP addresses for the `MX` records, e.g. `MX 11 smtp.example.com.` => `A 192.0.2.2` & `AAAA 2001:DB8::2`.

For both, `example.com` is `example.com`, not `*.example.com`. That kind of inheritance would also be impossible, as it would require an infinite amount of additional DNS queries. Using anything other than `ip4`/`ip6` mechanism should be avoided when possible to minimize the load on the DNS, and for this reason there is also a hard DNS lookup limit of 10 queries after which the SPF implementations MUST return `permerror` (RFC 7208, 4.6.4).

**TL;DR: Replace all `a` and `mx` mechanisms directly with the corresponding `ip4` and `ip6`**, e.g.

```
example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.2 +ip6:2001:DB8::2 -all"
```

---

Also, there is no inheritance from `example.com` to `sub.example.com`. This means an SPF record for `example.com` does not protect subdomains having `A` records. Therefore, for every `A` record you need an additional SPF record, or otherwise someone could use `user@smtp.example.com` as the envelope sender.

- If you want to use the hostname itself as an envelope sender:

  ```
  smtp.example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.2 +ip6:2001:DB8::2 -all"
  ```
- Or if you do not need it:

  ```
  smtp.example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 -all"
  ```

---

Let's expand your configuration for a better example, and remove the unnecessary `MX` record, assuming `smtp.example.com` is dedicated for outbound mail. Here, the `A` for the domain apex also points to the web server:

```
mail    IN A      192.0.2.1
mail    IN AAAA   2001:DB8::1
smtp    IN A      192.0.2.2
smtp    IN AAAA   2001:DB8::2
www     IN A      192.0.2.3
www     IN AAAA   2001:DB8::3

@       IN A      192.0.2.3
@       IN AAAA   2001:DB8::3
@       IN MX 10  mail.example.com.
```

Let's add SPF records, where every host can send mail as `example.com` and itself:

```
@       IN TXT    "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.0/30 +ip6:2001:DB8::0/126 -all"
mail    IN TXT    "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.1 +ip6:2001:DB8::1 -all"
smtp    IN TXT    "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.2 +ip6:2001:DB8::2 -all"
www     IN TXT    "v=spf1 +ip4:192.0.2.3 +ip6:2001:DB8::3 -all"
```